# When "taking address of temporary" error gets in a way of clean code

Tags: c++, c++11

I know this error message was discussed multiple times and reasons behind it are well-known. This questions is about different thing -- how to code a certain pattern (that would be trivial if not for that error).

There is a function `void foo(int const*, int const*, int const*)` where each parameter is `nullptr` when related data is not available. I used `int`, but it could be any type (number of arguments is not fixed either).

With MSVC (or in old days -- with `-fpermissive`) you could write code like this and it is quite easy on eyes:

```
int data_source::bar() { ... }

data_source* s1;
data_source* s2;
data_source* s3;
...
foo(
    s1 ? &s1->bar() : nullptr,
    s2 ? &s2->bar() : nullptr,
    s3 ? &s3->bar() : nullptr
);
```

Now, with modern GCC this fails to compile and `-fpermissive` doesn't seem to work anymore.

How would you structure this code to do the same while avoiding error? Is there a way to tell compiler "yes, I know but it's ok" (similar to `(void)x` cast to avoid `unused variable` warning)?

I came up with two ["solutions"](https://godbolt.org/g/NhwTAk) (don't like both of them):

```
template<class T> T const* addr(T const& v) { return &v; }
```

or even more dangerous:

```
template<class T> T* addr(T&& v) { return &v; }
```

this means more typing, harder to read and generally ugly.

This one tries to imitate what compiler is doing behind the scene, but unfortunately leads to way too much typing, one extra comparison (per parameter) and other inefficiencies in generated asm:

```
optional<int> v1 = [&]{ return s1 ? optional<int>(s1->bar()) : optional<int>(); }();
optional<int> v2 = [&]{ return s2 ? optional<int>(s2->bar()) : optional<int>(); }();
optional<int> v3 = [&]{ return s3 ? optional<int>(s3->bar()) : optional<int>(); }();
foo(
    v1 ? &v1.value() : nullptr,
    v2 ? &v2.value() : nullptr,
    v3 ? &v3.value() : nullptr
);
```

Comment: Should `&s1->bar()` really be valid at all? It returns an `int`, and taking the address of a temporary is ill-formed.

Comment: I would rather store them in a locally scoped integer, so I know the pointer is valid for the function call. There may be some extra lines, but they are short and clear.

Comment: The standard library has a `template <class T> const T* addressof(const T&&) = delete;` to specifically *avoid* taking the address of a temporary. So adding a new function for doing that might not be the best idea.

Comment: Just have the function **accept** an optional instead of taking addresses. Honestly, clean coders are all about "self-documenting" code. Well what's more self documenting? `baz(int const*)` or `baz(optional<int>)`!?

Comment: A better solution would be to avoid designing a function that expects pointers to temporary objects

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Yes, `&s1->bar()` isn't valid in C++ anymore. Which breaks certain coding pattern as described above. Question was -- "which pattern to use instead to get the same thing?"

Comment: @M.M There is nothing in `foo()` design that requires pointer to temporary object.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, that is why I put solution into quotes

Comment: @StoryTeller You end up with more typing and losing efficiency.

Comment: @C.M. - Your efficiency argument without measurements is pointless. A few machine instructions for `boost::optional` aren't going to to bring your machine to a crawl or make you stop being real time. And as for `std::optional`, that's a library type. It's built into the language. That may be optimized in almost magical ways. As for more typing, the last snippet in my answer should answer that.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't see a single reason why I should pay with "few machine instructions" and bunch of typing in a trivial case like this.

Comment: To make your code cleaner, since that also seems to be some holy goal for you. Oh, and taking the address of a temporary was **never** allowed in C++ (or C). MSVC deceived you into writing non-portable code.

Comment: @StoryTeller So, the bottomline is that C++ (as of now) can't implement this particular pattern (where in one branch you create object on stack and pass it's address as argument, and in another -- don't create object and pass nullptr) efficiently. Would you agree with this assessment?

Comment: No, not this particular pattern. I'll just add that it's unlikely to implement it in any foreseeable future either. Right now the shift is toward types like `std::optional`.

Comment: @StoryTeller Unfortunately, we don't always control entire codebase and `foo()` can be a C function (with `int` being some large struct). With one argument I can implement this pattern as `if(s1) { int x = s1->bar(); foo(&x); } else foo(0);`, but with multiple arguments you have to code a branch for each permutation. And using `std::optional` leads to less efficient code (according to my reading of generated asm). I can be wrong , of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1 is correct C++ code and apparently the only way to achieve my goal:

```
template<class T> T* addr(T&& v) { return &v; }

foo(
    s1 ? addr(s1->bar()) : nullptr,
    s2 ? addr(s2->bar()) : nullptr,
    s3 ? addr(s3->bar()) : nullptr
);
```

On a further note: since C++14 taking address of rvalue is no longer UB -- it is simply forbidden now, compiler is required to emit an error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that the language clashes with clean code. The problem is that you use a C-ish form of "optional" parameters as a form of misguided micro optimization. C++17 introduced a vocabulary type for that very purpose, the aptly named `std::optional`. I argue that `foo` better look like this:

```
void foo(std::optional<int>, std::optional<int>, std::optional<int>);
```

Which has a self-documenting feature that clean coders should like. Since it's also pass by value, no need to artificially mark it `const` in the interface. And finally, calling is not a problem:

```
auto extract_argument = [](data_source* s) {
  return s ? optional<int>{s->bar()} : optional<int>{};
};

foo(
    extract_argument(s1),
    extract_argument(s2),
    extract_argument(s2)
);
```

---

You tagged C++11, so I won't touch the above where `boost::optional` may be dropped as a stand in. But it should be noted, that in C++17, it can be done practically the same as your original code:

```
foo(
    s1 ? std::optional{s1->bar()} : std::nullopt,
    s2 ? std::optional{s2->bar()} : std::nullopt,
    s3 ? std::optional{s3->bar()} : std::nullopt
);
```

Specifying `std::optional` is required because we want the conditional expression to have a well defined type, but the "null" case can be specified with `std::nullopt`. And what's more, class template argument deduction means we don't need to specify the template parameter. So it's short, expressive, and to the point.

Comment: Here are problems with this: (a) sometimes you can't control `foo()` signature or it could be a C function; (b) it is less efficient; (c) language is a tool and when it's idiosyncrasies get in a way -- it is frustrating. I know behavior that I want -- if flag is ON initialize object on stack and pass it's address, otherwise pass null. C++ forces me to use quite verbose and sub-efficient solution to achieve my goal, this makes it not ideal for this particular case. I hoped there is a better way.

Answer (score -1):

If `foo` tries to dereference the non-NULL pointers it gets as arguments, then calling it with

```
foo(
    s1 ? &s1->bar() : nullptr,
    s2 ? &s2->bar() : nullptr,
    s3 ? &s3->bar() : nullptr
);
```

leads to undefined behavior. If you would rather find a way to tell the compiler "I know what I am doing. Shut up and do it", you are being careless and arrogant.

If `foo` does not dereference the non-NULL pointers, you can use:

```
int temp;
foo(
    s1 ? &temp : nullptr,
    s2 ? &temp : nullptr,
    s3 ? &temp : nullptr
);
```

and avoid the calls to `data_source::bar()`.

In either case, use of

```
foo(
    s1 ? &s1->bar() : nullptr,
    s2 ? &s2->bar() : nullptr,
    s3 ? &s3->bar() : nullptr
);
```

is not warranted at all.

Comment: The lifetime of temporaries is the full expression, i.e. the `foo( )` call. That means they're destroyed only after `foo` returns. And I don't see any other reason to believe it's UB, either.

Comment: @MSalters - calling operator & on an rvalue is UB. Otherwise this whole discussion would become "it's a bug in gcc. End of story." Unfortunately GCC is correct to follow the standard.

Comment: @RustyX built-in operator& on an rvalue is ill-formed. overloaded operator& is allowed and is not UB.

Comment: `foo` doesn't need to dereference pointer to get UB -- you get it by simply taking address of rvalue. `int temp` case is not going to work for large types -- I don't want to initialize potentially huge object in (s1 == nullptr) case. Use of `s1 ? &s1->bar() : nullptr` is (actually was) warranted because it allowed you to avoid exactly that initialization.

Comment: @C.M., if `s1->bar()` returns a huge object, you will be better of returning a `const&` to it. In that case, the problem is moot.

Comment: @C.M., I feel like you are trying to account for some constraints without making clear what those constraints are.

Comment: @RSahu there is nothing wrong with returning huge objects by value thanks to wonders of RVO